# Unity - Duck volume of audio source inside a boxed area

Tags: unity, audio, sound-effects

I'm trying to lower the volume of an outside ambient wind sound while the player is inside a building or room. Is there any way in Unity to do this without scripting? Or would I have to script this to check whether the player is in a certain collider to duck (or lowpass filter) the sound?

The room is seamlessly in the scene's outside environment.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way without scripting, but you can have a Collider as trigger around the room or building, so that it covers the inside but not the outside.
OnTriggerEnter you lower the volume and OnTriggerExit you raise it again.
So yes, try option two, it shouldn't be much effort. :)